# I don‘t have member function installNativeEventFilter

Tags: c++, qt

That's strange, w have the member function installEventFilter()

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.SerialPortInit();
    //w.installNativeEventFilter(&w);
    w.installNativeEventFilter(&w);
    w.show();
    qDebug() << "hello Wolrd";
    return a.exec();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftk6G.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, the rule of thumb is don't post any screenshots, instead put a **minimal reproducible example** code in a code block and explain what's the problem with it.

Comment: installNativeEventFilter() is a function of [QCoreAppplication](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#installNativeEventFilter), not of [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html) nor QMainWindow.

Comment: @chehrlic thank you.I change it into a.installNativeEventFilter(&w), that's OK.